# White corrosion on videocard

Tags: graphics-card

I have White corrosion on my video card, how is it possible that the corrosion gets there, is this because of bad materials? Can this impact the lifetime of my card?

[image: Hd5570 white corrosion]
[image: Hd5570 white corrosion]

Comment: How old is the card? What conditions has it been operating in? Has it been stored for a long time? And if so, how?

Comment: The card is in my PC for almost 2,5 years. My PC stands in my own room. So it’s always nice and warm there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears to be the result of the manufacturing process. As you can see, the residue follows a fairly clean line around solder terminations. Therefore, it is likely the card was not cleaned properly after being fluxed and soldered.

Although this article is old, here is a paper discussing the white residue - [THE NATURE OF WHITE RESIDUE ON PRINTED CIRCUIT ASSEMBLIES](http://www.kester.com/Portals/0/Knowledge_Base_Articles/White_Residue.pdf)

As far as affecting the life of the card. That depends on what chemical it is. I would say that if you have been using the card successfully for more than 2 years, you are probably alright. If this were new from the box, I would be more concerned.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. But is there any way that I can damage the card when I remove the white stuff?

Comment: I wouldn't do it just in case, it will be in your computer so you won't notice anyways.

Comment: Not knowing what chemical is in the residue, I wouldn't risk a chemical reaction to a cleaning agent. I will refer to a famous quote; `If it ain't broke, don't fix it`.

Answer (score 1):

The "corroded" areas are areas where components were added (possibly by hand) in the construction process after the main automated assembly.

From the shape of the patterns, probably dip or wave soldering was used for these areas, and this leaves a thin coat of flux on the board which slowly turns white over time.  This flux is "mostly harmless", but can slightly contribute to corrosion down the road.

You can try cleaning with alcohol, though it may not work very well.  The "old standard" for flux removal was carbon-tet (now a no-no), and I don't know what they use now.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if it's stored in a close and moist place (could be the computer itself).
Eventually, it can affect it's performance and even kill you card (from my own experience).
Best thing you can do clean with clean alcohol and tooth brush, and keep the storage place more ventilated.